# iOS 6 Custom URL Scheme Launch Images wrong

Tags: ios, ios6, url-scheme

I have implemented custom URL schemes in my application. Also I have different names for the splash image using the **UILaunchImageFile** key in the info.plist. The documentations says:

> If your app supports one or more custom URL schemes, it can also
>   provide a custom launch image for each URL scheme. When the system
>   launches your app to handle a URL, it displays the launch image
>   associated with the scheme of the given URL. In this case, the format
>   for your launch image filenames are as follows:
>
> ```
> <basename>-<url_scheme><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
> ```
>
> The  modifier is a string representing the name of your
>   URL scheme name. For example, if your app supports a URL scheme with
>   the name myscheme, the system looks for an image with the name
>   Default-myscheme.png (or Default-myscheme@2x.png for Retina displays)
>   in the app’s bundle. If the app’s Info.plist file includes the
>   UILaunchImageFile key, the base name portion changes from Default to
>   the custom string you provide in that key.
>
> Note: You can combine a URL scheme modifier with orientation
>   modifiers. If you do this, the format for the filename is
>
> ```
> <basename>-<url_scheme><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png.
> ```
>
> For more information about the launch orientation modifiers, see
>   “Providing Launch Images for Different Orientations.”

on iOS 5 the correct splash image for the scheme is presented but on iOS 6 it shows the normal  splash image. I discovered that if I rename it using the "Default" basename it works fine on iOS 6 but this will mess up my project. Thus I will not be able to support multiple versions

Anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well issue solved. FYI everyone out there that has value for the key UILaunchImageFile with a file extension at the end of the base name. This is the problem. So do not include file extensions like ".png" in your basename for the launch image!!!